# libcurl POST, remove extra data thrown in by Curl

Tags: http, post, libcurl

Anyone know of a way to remove this from the Curl post...?

```
" method="post" name="form_reply" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It's getting tacked on the the POST line of the message. ie...

```
POST /someurl/Topic/comment/replycreate/27537?sp=1**" method="post" name="form_reply" enctype="multipart/form-data">** HTTP/1.1
```

Thanks in advance...!

OK, More info...
BTW: This is C, NOT PHP

---

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode result;
char errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
int status=FALSE;
BufHandle *Bufhandle = CreateBufHandle(BUFSIZE);
memset(&errorBuffer,0x0,sizeof(errorBuffer));
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, GetPtrToSlist(S));
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  GetParameterByName(S, "useragent"));
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, GetParameterByName(S, "cookiefile"));
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  GetParameterByName(S, "cookiefile"));
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, &errorBuffer);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
  //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, buf);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)Bufhandle);
  result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_slist_free_all(GetPtrToSlist(S));
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  if(result == CURLE_OK)
  {
    status = TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error: [%d] - %s\n",result, errorBuffer);
    status = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're apparently using the API wrong, but this isn't enough information.  The relevant code might help.

Comment: "You're apparently using the API wrong, but this isn't enough information. The relevant code might help. – Matthew Flaschen"    Please feel free to Enlighten me with the CORRECT API

Answer (score 0):

Curl will automatically append: 
" method="post" name="form_reply" enctype="multipart/form-data">

anytime you do a post and the url includes parameters, or what it thinks are parameters being passed.

/someurl/Topic/comment/replycreate/27537**?sp=1**

So when you remove the '?' question mark, and the data after the question mark, curl no longer appends any weird looking post parameters...

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce your problem, URI comes out exactly as ordered. I'm using libcurl 7.22 and the following code to build the request:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(case_http_session_libcurl)
{
  test_site::site test_site;
  std::string url = "http://localhost:";
  url += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(test_site.start());
  url += "/post?some=1&data=2";
  char error[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

  CURL *curl;
  int status=FALSE;
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl)
  {
    curl_slist* slist = NULL;
    slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Expect:");
    slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Some-Rubbish: here");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  "testing goes here");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, &error[0]);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=being;posted=1");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_on_recv);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, 0);
    CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(slist);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    if(result == CURLE_OK)
    {
      status = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Error: [%d] - %s\n",result, error);
      status = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

and the request received by HTTP server is:

```
POST /post?some=1&data=2 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: testing goes here
Host: localhost:16385
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Some-Rubbish: here
Content-Length: 19
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

data=being;posted=1
```